# Doctrine collection is null upon object initialization [In some cases only]

Tags: php, symfony, collections, doctrine-orm

This is my problem: I create an object, then I get a collection from that object. For some objects, in some controllers, this collections return an empty `CollectionArray` Object, for some it returns just null.

Reading in SO, they say it is better to always initialize all `ManyToMany` relationships in the entities constructor, is this really the case? Where is this documented?

This is an example of the problem:

```
$p = new Person();
$p->getRelatives(); // null, should be empty CollectionArray.
```

In the mean time, in another Controller Class...

```
$w = new Woman();
w->getMen(); // this returns an empty CollectionArray class -.-
```

Hope you guys can point me in the right direction, I really don't want to go through all my entities and create a constructor for them just because of this!

Besides, whats really annoying is this non deterministic behavior in which the collections are returned.

Comment: In your constructor you need to create an ArrayCollection as clearly specified by the documentation.  The reason you feel that it is non-deterministic is that when you pull entities from the database then the collection is created by Doctrine.  Doctrine does not call the constructor when hydrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And that's the reason, why the documentation says, [all collections should be initialized](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#initializing-collections):

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @Entity */
class User
{
    /** @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group") */
    private $groups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getGroups()
    {
        return $this->groups;
    }
}
```

And the time, if a collection is null or not null, if not initialised is determenistic. Without initialisation the `$groups` field only contains an instance of `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection` if the user is retrieved from Doctrine, however not after you instantiated a fresh instance of the User. When your user entity is still new `$groups` will obviously be null.